# Move text between two Objects (even if i will change objects positions)

Tags: animation

I New here

I want to Move text between two objects, for example, I want to do animation in a certain second.

An object moves from the location of a particular object to the location of another object regardless of the current location of the object to which it should arrive.

For example I have two cubes in the file (below Moshe and David), and text (hereinafter "Zvika").

I want from 10 to 11 seconds The text "Zvika" will leave the cube Moshe, and will reach the cube David, even if I then arrange the dice in another order.

Comment: The Omar Answer worked!!!, now i want to move the circle (in example) to anothe cube location after sec, can someone can help me how to make the nodes PLESE

Answer (score 0):

You can use Animation Nodes for this. A simple linear interpolation between the two position using the *Animate Vector* node. The *Delay node* is used to set the frame at which the animation will start.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you i add the animation nodes and do the tree and it's work